# Usage of GetProcAddress confused non executing

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, dllexport

I might be missing something very easy but still i confronted this problem that i couldnt solve. I create a dll with these functions,

```
extern "C"{
  __declspec(dllexport) void some();
  __declspec(dllexport) void printer();
}

void printer()
{
    printf("printing...\n");
}
```

i compile it using cmake

```
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE
cmake --build . --config Release
```

the i load it from my dllloader.cpp

```
int main() {
  HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");

  if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL) {
    std::cout << "cannot locate the .dll file" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "it has been called" << std::endl;
    
  }
  
if(GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "printer") == NULL){
    
}else{
    std::cout <<"not null" << std::endl;
}

    std::cout << GetLastError() << " err" << std::endl;
    
    getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

So `GetLastError` returns 0 but nothing is printed, in the original file it is pretty much the same, the function is more that just a `printf()` call but the function gets loaded, how do we run it ? I know i might be missing something, just function does not execute. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You have to save the return value and use that to call the function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/getprocaddress?view=msvc-160

Comment: in what variable type can i store the value of a `void` function, in that link the value seems built in to me @RetiredNinja

Comment: also is there a simpler way of running it as loading it from the address ? @RetiredNinja

Comment: Where in your code do you think you are trying to invoke `printer()`? If I just read your code and infer meanings, it says something like "if the procedure 'printer' does not have an address in `hGetProcIDDLL` then do nothing, else send `"not null"` to the standard output." (Or should I take *"nothing is printed"* literally and assume neither `"not null"` nor `"it has been called"` is printed"?)

Comment: i just learned that i need to invoke it @JaMiT figuring out how. I used this way before i remember that getprocaddress directly ran the fuction, i might be remembering wrong, or it could be a function with a different name.

Comment: @turmuka OK, shift to past tense: where in your code **did** you think you are trying to invoke `printer()`? You wrote the code, and expected `printer()` to be executed. Why? If you cannot point to a specific line where you believed `printer()` should be called, you should have spent a lot less time being mystified by your results and more directly asked [How do I call a function from my DLL during run-time linking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126726/how-do-i-call-a-function-from-my-dll-during-run-time-linking)

Comment: I solved it, i used `FARPROC xf`as a return value then use `xf()` @JaMiT

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef void(*my_dll_print)();      // function pointer to print method of dll
int main() 
{
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");

    if (hGetProcIDDLL == nullptr) 
        std::cout << "cannot locate the .dll file" << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << "it has been called" << std::endl;

    my_dll_print print_method = reinterpret_cast<my_dll_print>(GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "printer"));       // Extract method address and create pointer
    if (print_method == nullptr)
        std::cout << "is null" << std::endl;
    else
        print_method();     // Call dll method

    std::cout << GetLastError() << " err" << std::endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Try to use `nullptr` instead `NULL` to check `pointer`.

`GetProcAdrress` retrieves the address of an exported function or variable from the specified dynamic-link library! and makes no function call. You must first assign to function pointer then make call to pointed function!

Comment: `1` The function pointer type `my_dll_print` is missing a calling convention. `2` `GetProcAddress` requires you to pass the *decorated* symbol, unless the export has been renamed (by e.g. using a .def file). `3` `GetLastError` is called too late. At the it's called its return value has become meaningless already.

Comment: LoadLibrary returns an HMODULE

Comment: [What is the difference between HINSTANCE and HMODULE?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903)